# Spring Boot scheduled application updates

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to automate instalation/update process for my app. It's web application in spring boot. Users run this application on their own servers which usually isn't accessible from my build servers.

**Requirements**

1. installation is simple
2. update can be scheduled and is done automatically
3. fewest dependencies possible
4. runs on both windows server and linux
5. reliability & security

**Current prototype**

Our current prototype is based on docker. There are actually 6 docker images (our app is 2 dockers, [watchtower](https://github.com/v2tec/watchtower), monitoring agent, zuul + eureka, certbot).

Installation:

1. download and install docker
2. download & run a script (it's very thin wrapper around docker compose)

Upgrade:

1. user checks release notes and schedules an upgrade
2. app sends to our build server request for new version
3. image for new version is built & published to repository
4. watchtower automatically downloads & updates it

This prototype works but it's not very reliable and it feels like overengineering.

Do you have experience with something similar? I will be very happy for opinions how to make it simpler.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Spring Batch? It's got a scheduling API that you can run within the spring boot application.